# Which design pattern for an alerter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm really struggling to come up with a design pattern for an Alerter I'm building. Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do:

A person wants to get an alert by weather type (rain, snow, sun, etc.). A person also has a choice of alert method (email, sms, slack channel, hipchat room, etc.)

I need to: have a class which takes in a weather type. Then it retrieves all the people that care about that weather type. Then it loops through all the people and sends them their alert (based on the person's alert type preference).

I'm trying to stay away from the smell of switch statements, but maybe it's not as bad as it seems?

Here's my basic outline, but it seems like it should be done "better":

```
public class Alerter
{
    private readonly WeatherType _weatherType;

    public Alerter(WeatherType weatherType)
    {
        _weatherType = weatherType;
    }

    public void SendAlerts()
    {
        var people = PersonRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);

        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            switch (person.AlertType)
            {
                case Email:
                    var e = new EmailAlerter();
                    e.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
                    return;
                case SMS:
                    var s = new SmsAlerter();
                    s.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The people who want to get alerts are they observers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Probably?  I'm not quite sure how to adapt my code above to fit it though.  it seems like that's what I already have set up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing the right Design Pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Comment: Note that copying questions across sites is strongly discouraged.  Always pick the best site for your question, and post it only there.

Comment: Don't go shopping for a pattern. Express the problem you are trying to solve, and look for a solution. Perhaps that solution will be similar to solutions to other problems. But saying "I'm really struggling to come up with a design pattern for an Alerter I'm building" reeks of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Closely related: questions on [best practices are often indicative of failing to understand the problem being solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var people = PersonRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);
```

The first thing to note is that you are using a service locator here, which is widely recognised as an anti-pattern. So you could improve that by injecting an instance of `IPersonRepository` into the `Alerter` constructor.

```
switch (person.AlertType)
{
    case Email:
        ...
}
```

The switch statement has a lot of duplicated code as each case is selecting a type and invoking `SendToPerson` on that type. This could be replaced with a factory (injected via the constructor, of course) that returns an instance of `IAlerter` and the `SendToPerson` method called on that:

```
public void SendAlerts()
{
    var people = _personRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);

    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        var alerter = _alerterFactory(person.AlertType);
        alerter.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
    }
}
```

(note, I have assumed the `return`'s are a mistake in your code, otherwise it would only ever alert the first person.)

Answer (score -2):

Since every user has its own prefered alert method (probably coming from some user settings), this information belongs to the user (= should be part of the user's internal state, as an attribute). `User` objects must be **responsible** for deciding how to send the alerts and it must be **opaque** for the caller.

```
public void SendAlerts()
{
    var people = PersonRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);

    foreach (Person person in people)
    {
        person.send(_weatherType); //inside it's using EmailAlerter, SmsAlerter, etc.
    }
}
```

That way, you get rid of any switch. Note that I'm not using any design pattern (exception maybe dependency injection).

Design patterns are no silver bullet: they are good servants but bad masters. Don't let all your design decisions be guided by them, but use them only when you face a problem that a design pattern has already resolved.